# Prove probability of a sum of a sequence of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, integration

How can you prove that if $t$ is less than or equal to $1$, that the probability of the sum of a sequence of uniform random variables being less than or equal to $t$ equals $t^k/k!$ ?

In other words:

Prove if $t \leq 1$, $$P(U_1+U_2 + \dots +U_k \leq t)=\frac{t^k}{k!}$$

My thought is that integration is needed *CDF*, but I can't figure out how to analytically solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Conditioning on the value of $U_k$, for $t\leqslant1$, write
$$
P[U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_k\leqslant t]=\int_0^tP[U_1+U_2+\cdots+U_{k-1}\leqslant t-s]\mathrm ds,
$$
then apply the recursion hypothesis.

**Note:** The CDF is not so pleasant to write down on each interval $(i-1,i)$ for $2\leqslant i\leqslant k-1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can reason about this geometrically.  First of all, all uniform variables must be less than or equal to $t$, which gives a hypercube of volume (probability) $t^k$.  Then you need the sum to be less than or equal to $t$, which gives a simplex inside the hypercube. In general, the ratio of the volume of a simplex generated by basis vectors with non-negative coefficients that sum to $\leq 1$, to the volume of the parallelopiped generated by the same basis vectors with  non-negative coefficients all $ \leq 1$, is $1/k!$ where $k$ is the dimension. So you get $t^k/k!$.